# How to vertically align EditText and ProgressBar in horizontal LinearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar, android-linearlayout, vertical-alignment

In my layout I have four blocks like these:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="@string/freq_1_50" />
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textScore1"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="50%" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Resulting in this picture in the android emulator:

[image]

The obvious questions is: how do I go about in vertically aligning the EditText and progressbar?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the desired result of adding the center attribute:

[image]

Problem solved!

Comment: I'm curious, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> ```
> <LinearLayout
> android:orientation="horizontal"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> ```
>
> **android:gravity = "center"**>

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/label1"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/freq_1_50" />
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textScore1"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:text="50%" />
```

Comment: Yep, I had found it myself from this: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/   Thanks anyway!

Comment: Desired output screen shot posted in question. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:gravity = "center"` to your Linear layout above